# Entering file from data to an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, sorting, input

So I'm working on a hangman program and I've gotten the input file which contains the words that I need. The question now is how can I put the words that I've entered from the file into an array?
any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_NUMS = 200;   // Constant for the maximum number of words.
const int MAX_GUESSES = 8;
const string LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";


//function prototypes
char   inputLetter();
int    findChar(char letter, string word);
string getGuessedWord(string secretWord, string lettersGuessed);

//main function
int main()
{
                // holds one word from input file
string secretWord;              // holds secret word to be guessed
string words[MAX_NUMS];         // holds list of words from input file
int randomValue;                // holds index of secret word
int count = 0;                  // holds number of words in the file

// Declare an ifstream object named myFile and open an input file
string line;

ifstream myfile ("p4words.txt");

if (myfile.is_open())

{

    while (! myfile.eof() )

    {

        getline (myfile,line);

        cout << line << endl;

    }

    myfile.close();

}

else cout << "Unable to open file";

// Input words from a file into words array

cout << count << " words loaded." << endl;

srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
```

Comment: Put them in the array instead of or in addition to outputting the words to the console? And a `std::vector` is nicer so you don't have to worry about a "maximum" size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to put them into an array, just assign into the next index each time:

```
while (getline(myfile, line)) {
    words[count] = line;
    ++count;
    if (count == MAX_NUMS) {
        // this is all the space we have
        break;
    }
}
```

Or just `getline` directly into the array:

```
while (getline(myfile, words[count])) {
    ++count;
    if (count == MAX_NUMS) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Although for this exact thing we have `vector`, which obviates the need for the count and doesn't have a cap:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;

while (getline(myfile, line)) {
    words.push_back(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barry's answer

You can also use commandline execution and change the input stream for example after the creation of .exe file (after compilation/build) if the name of the file is "program1.exe"
and the text file is "input.txt" (in the same directory) input can be given to file via a this text file by changing the input stream

Open commandline in the same directory and write

```
 program1.exe<input.txt
```

the original program depending on your needs can be like

```
int main(){
    int arr[6];
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
        std::cin>>arr[i];
    }
    std::cout<<"data entered";
}
```

And the input.txt would be like

> 52 14 24 23 45

Similarly you can change the output stream and save the output to a different file say output.txt by writing in commandline

```
program1.exe<input.txt>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the vector directly from a `istream_iterator` (`#include <iterator>`), such as:

```
std::vector<std::string> words((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myfile)), 
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

The double `()` in `(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myfile))` are needed to avoid the most vexing parse. In C++11 can simply use brace-initialization and write

```
std::vector<std::string> words{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myfile), {}};
```